# Flex Layout not following flex percentages

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am trying out flex layout in my angular app.
I am trying to create a layout with base as : 
[image]

I have tried writing a code.

my .html file

```
<div flexLayout = "row">
  <div fxFlex="100%" class="first_bar">
     Second Div
  </div>
</div>

<div flexLayout = "row">
  <div fxFlex="100%" class="second_bar">
     Third Div
  </div>
</div>

<div flexLayout = "row">
  <div fxFlex="12%" class="third_bar_1">
     Fourth Div 1
    <!-- <h5>third div</h5> -->
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="86%" class="third_bar_2">
     Fourth Div 2
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.first_bar{
    background-color: #cdf7fb;
    height: 6%;
}

.second_bar{
    background-color: #cdf7;
    height: 12px;     
}

.third_bar_1{
    background-color: #6390c3;
}

.third_bar_2{   
    background-color: white;
}
```

But my output looks like

[image]

Flex Layout is not working properly and height of divs is also not being followed.
Can some one help me with this?

Comment: I did not understand where you used flex

Comment: `<div flexLayout = "row">
  <div fxFlex="100%" class="first_bar">
`

Comment: is this not flex? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: if you do not use `display: flex` is not flex

Comment: Did you import FlexLayoutModule into the module? It never gives any warnings if you dont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start space-between" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div class="first_bar">
          Second Div
        </div>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-bewteen start" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div fxFlex="12" class="second_bar">
          Side
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="88" fxLayout="column"  fxLayoutAlign="space-bewteen" fxLayoutGap="10px">
          <div [ngClass]="['third_bar_1']">
          first
          </div>
          <div [ngClass]="['third_bar_2']">
          second
          <div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.first_bar{
        background-color: #cdf7fb;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .second_bar{
        background-color: #cdf7;
        height: calc(100vh - 200px);  
    }

    .third_bar_1{
        background-color: #6390c3;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .third_bar_2{   
        border:1px solid red;
        height: calc(100vh - 315px);
    }
```

Working stackblitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-nmt9av?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I have used the same code but all the divs ended up coming one after another

Comment: check the link I have given

Comment: I have copied the code of html and css code from the stackblitz, but the same thing. Should I import or install anything for flex to work?

Comment: It seems, your flex is not installed properly .. to install npm i @angular/flex-layout --save  then import the FlexLayoutModule to app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

### Simple use flex and wrap all with div

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.first_line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.first_bar {
  background-color: #cdf7fb;
  height: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.all_below {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.second_wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
}

.second_bar {
  background-color: #6390c3;
  height: 100%;
}

.third_wrap {
  width: 80%;
}

.third_bar_1 {
  background-color: #cdf7;
  height: 100px;
}

.third_bar_2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="main">
  <div flexLayout="row" class="first_line">
    <div fxFlex="100%" class="first_bar">
      Second Div
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="all_below">
    <div flexLayout="row" class="second_wrap">
      <div fxFlex="100%" class="second_bar">
        Third Div
      </div>
    </div>

    <div flexLayout="row" class="third_wrap">
      <div fxFlex="12%" class="third_bar_1">
        Fourth Div 1
        <!-- <h5>third div</h5> -->
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="86%" class="third_bar_2">
        Fourth Div 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```